# Border Dropshadow affecting contents inside

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to setup a border with a dropshadow, however the issue is that the dropshadow does't come around the border rather it comes on the context inside it. How can I get this around the border please?

Code:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" CornerRadius="10" Margin="20" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness=".5" Height="30">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="12" Color="Black" Direction="315" Opacity="0.8"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Ex Dates Filter Start:13/02/2014 End 14/02/2014" Margin="5"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="X" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
            </Grid>                        
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply the effect on border instead of Grid:

```
<Border>
  <Border.Effect>
     <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="12" Color="Black" Direction="315"
                       Opacity="0.8"/>
  </Border.Effect>
  <Grid> ... </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure why you'd go with the first instead of the second option?  Seems redundant.

Comment: Yeah I posted and later though to keep it there. May be I should take that down. It serves no purpose anyhow.. Thanks..!! :)